# db.printCollectionStats() error

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongo-java, mongojs

I am getting the following error when I run:

db.printCollectionStats()

```
error: {
        "$err" : "stale config on lazy receive :: caused by :: $err: \"[myzips.zips] shard version not ok in Client::Context: this shard contains versioned chunks for myzips.zips, but no version set in request ( ns : myzips.zip...\" ( ns : myzips.zips, received : 0|0||000000000000000000000000, wanted : 1|1||50fdd55b14faa2aa46422a7a, recv )",
        "code" : 9996
} at src/mongo/shell/query.js:128
```

what does this mean?

Comment: I would suggest asking this question [mongodb google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mongodb-user), since this looks to be an internal issue (related to sharding maybe).

Comment: Did this error occur after you tried sharding or changing any configuration?

Comment: While changing configuration